# Remove methods from TOC

Tags: doxygen

When generating documentation, the TOC (navigation) includes entries for classes, namespaces, and methods.
I would like to remove the entries for methods; this just clutters up the TOC, since we have hundreds of methods. Is there an easy way to do this?
I have edited the layout file, but I think because these are nested below that top level, it isn't in there? Or I am missing it.

```
<navindex>
<tab type="mainpage" visible="no" title=""/>
<tab type="pages" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
<tab type="modules" visible="no" title="Macros" intro=""/>
<tab type="namespaces" visible="no" title=""/>
<tab type="namespacelist" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
  <tab type="namespacemembers" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
  <tab type="interfaces" visible="no" title="">
  <tab type="interfacelist" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
  <tab type="interfaceindex" visible="$ALPHABETICAL_INDEX" title=""/> 
  <tab type="interfacehierarchy" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
</tab>
<tab type="classes" visible="no" title="Objects">
  <tab type="classlist" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
  <tab type="classindex" visible="no" title=""/>
  <tab type="hierarchy" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
  <tab type="classmembers" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
</tab>
<tab type="structs" visible="no" title="">
  <tab type="structlist" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
  <tab type="structindex" visible="no" title=""/> 
</tab>
<tab type="exceptions" visible="no" title="">
  <tab type="exceptionlist" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
  <tab type="exceptionindex" visible="no" title=""/> 
  <tab type="exceptionhierarchy" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
</tab>
<tab type="file" visible="no" title="">
  <tab type="filelist" visible="no" title="" intro="List"/>
  <tab type="globals" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
</tab>
<tab type="examples" visible="no" title="" intro=""/> 
</navindex>
```

Update: Included an image that show what I do not want to appear in the TOC. The challenge is that I still need the documentation for these items to appear in the output. SEPARATE_MEMBER_PAGES is set to NO, so the content for these methods is on the same page as the class - I just need them removed from the navigation.

[image: Menu]

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Did you have a look at the possibilities of the `DoxygenLayout.xml` (see https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html#layout and https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_layout_file), might remove a bit much but it might be a starting point.

Comment: I'm using 1.9.1. I have edited the layout file, but I think because these are nested below that top level, it isn't in there? Or I am missing it. Added a picture above of the top part of my doxygen layout file; almost everything is set not to be visible...

Comment: Can you add an image indicating which methods you mean?

Comment: There are also settings for e.g. `publicmethods`, looks like they don't have a `visible` attribute, but I think they have so you can try set them to `visible=no`  as well.

Comment: Did you have a look at the `publicmethods` settings etc in the layout file?

Comment: I did look at the publicmethods settings - but I think they are all in the layout definitions, which controls what is present on the page and not what is present in the navigation? 
Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: My comment was just without testing, though there is no visible. As far as I can see it currently is not supported.